install BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.32) gunzip unknown compression format error
I am trying to run pod install on my Flutter application to build ios but currently getting the follow error:
# We are renaming openssl to openssl_grpc so that there is no conflict with openssl if it exists
find . -type f \( -path '*.h' -or -path '*.cc' -or -path '*.c' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 sed -E -i'.grpc_back' 's;#include <openssl/;#include <openssl_grpc/;g'

# Include of boringssl_prefix_symbols.h does not follow Xcode import style. We add the package
# name here so that Xcode knows where to find it.
find . -type f \( -path '*.h' -or -path '*.cc' -or -path '*.c' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 sed -E -i'.grpc_back' 's;#include <boringssl_prefix_symbols.h>;#include <openssl_grpc/boringssl_prefix_symbols.h>;g'

gunzip: unknown compression format

So far these are the steps I have tried:

Reinstall cocoapods: sudo gem uninstall cocoapods and then sudo gem install cocoapods (I have also tried to use homebrew but still got the error)
cd ios
My podfile is

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
end



Remove Pods/ folder and podfile.lock: rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
flutter clean and then flutter pub get
when running pod repo update and then pod install, I get:

The error seems to be related to installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.32) but it doesn't seem to be a network error.
I also tried to increase the max size of the http post buffer with git config --global http.postbuffer 10000m but to no avail. I have also tried to use different networks and VPNs with no change.
It also seems that cloud_firestore relies on BoringSSL-GRPC being installed, because when I have a podfile without dependencies on it, there is an error that cloud_firestore module is not found and the build fails.
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end


Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Note: the first block is the error. I didn't include all of it, because terminal prints out the file which gunzip wasn't able to decode (which is a file from BoringSSL).  The gunzip command is run automatically when I call pods install (cocoapods) and it's trying to install the BoringSSL-GRPC pods.

Also I played around with it for a day and resolved it. Basically I had a base64 (non-GNU) version that had some compatibility issues with the standard behaviour of base64. So I just reinstalled the GNU version of base64.

Great, glad you solved it! Can you post that as an answer please?

I'd also be interested in what the incompatibility was. You can't go wrong with base64, surely?

As discussed in comments, the problem was

I had a base64 (non-GNU) version that had some compatibility issues with the standard behaviour of base64. So I just reinstalled the GNU version of base64.

